# dbt get value from agate.Row to string

Tags: dbt

I want to run a macro in a `COPY INTO` statement to S3 bucket. Apparently in snowflake I can't do dynamic path. So I'm doing a hacky way to solve this.

```
{% macro unload_snowflake_to_s3() %}

    {# Get all tables and views from the information schema. #}
    {%- set query -%}
        select concat('COPY INTO @MY_STAGE/year=', year(current_date()), '/my_file FROM (SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) from my_table)');
    {%- endset -%}

    -- {%- set final_query = run_query(query) -%}
    -- {{ dbt_utils.log_info(final_query) }}
    -- {{ dbt_utils.log_info(final_query.rows.values()[0]) }}


    {%- do run_query(final_query.columns.values()[0]) -%}

    -- {% do final_query.print_table() %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Based on above macros, what I'm trying to do is:

1. Use `CONCAT` to add `year` in the bucket path. Hence, the query becomes a string.
2. Use the concatenated query to `do run_query()`again to actually run the `COPY INTO` statement.

Output and error I got from dbt log:

```
09:06:08  09:06:08 + | column                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | data_type |
| ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | --------- |
| COPY INTO @MY_STAGE/year=', year(current_date()), '/my_file FROM (SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) from my_table) | Text      |

09:06:08  09:06:08 + <agate.Row: ('COPY INTO @MY_STAGE/year=2022/my_file FROM (SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) from my_table)')>
09:06:09  Encountered an error while running operation: Database Error
  001003 (42000): SQL compilation error:
  syntax error line 1 at position 0 unexpected '<'.
root@2c50ba8af043:/dbt#
```

I think the error is that I didn't extract the row and column specifically which is in `agate` format. How can I convert/extract this to string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have better luck with [`dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_query_results_as_dict-source).

But you don't need to use your database to construct that path. The jinja context has a [`run_started_at`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_started_at) variable that is a Python datetime object, so you can build your string in jinja, without hitting the database:

```
{% set yr = run_started_at.strftime("%Y") %}
{% set query = 'COPY INTO @MY_STAGE/year=' ~ yr ~ '/my_file FROM (SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(*) from my_table)' %}
```

Finally, depending on how you're calling this macro you probably want to gate this whole thing with an `{% if execute %}` flag, so dbt doesn't do the `COPY` when it's parsing your models.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict` function to get rid of agate part. Maybe after that your copy statement can work.

```
{%- set final_query = dbt_utils.get_query_results_as_dict(query) -%}
    {{log(final_query ,true)}}

    {% for keys,val in final_query.items() %}
        
        {{log(keys,true)}}
        {{log( val ,true)}}
    {% endfor %}
```

if you run like this you will see `('COPY INTO @MY_STAGE/year=', year(current_date())...')` and lastly remove `('')` by

```
{%- set final_val=val | replace('(', '')| replace(')', '') | replace("'", '') -%}
```

That's it.